# Mongodb / JS: find the minimum (earliest) date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, meteor

I'm trying to find the minimum date of all documents in a collection. I have approached this so far with a sort function and taking the first one that I find, see here:

```
earliestTime = function (kitUser) {
    'use strict';
    var res, earliestTime;
    res = Cards.findOne({ kit: kitUser }, { fields: { created: 1 } }, { sort: { created: 1 } });
    console.log('Created date: ' + res.created);
    earliestTime = new Date(res.created - 20000);
    console.log('Earliest time: ' + earliestTime);
    return earliestTime;
};
```

I then subtract 20 seconds from the value I've found and return that value to `insert` a new document which has 20 seconds less in the created fields than the earliest I've found before.

```
modifierObject = {};
modifierObject.created = earliestTime(kitUser);
```

The function `earliestTime` delivers the right results when I look at the console output:

```
I20160516-15:53:14.849(7)? Created date: Wed Apr 06 2016 12:00:11 GMT+0700 (ICT)
I20160516-15:53:14.849(7)? Earliest time: Wed Apr 06 2016 11:59:51 GMT+0700 (ICT)
```

However, when this function is called 21 times with a couple of read/write operations in between each call, each inserted document has the same timestamp in the created field:

```
{ "_id" : "xcd3EfKfS6iLGvcsP", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "bvL3f8NHHZM8Ytdma", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "gAirEbicdWJz9CELB", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "kgAg6Jt2P89mTJYgN", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "xeqR5K2fxNmgEv4bb", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "PgPimNRxj2zBuS8M2", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "snwEWeXpn4Ampsito", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "8RCS8YQLxY7tY6Ruk", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "tEqRJs49RNvCzkMz6", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "PJnZ7Z4WH6rTTw626", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "J2L6KPhzxcva3rttJ", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "YR5R6ShakPxCXgj54", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "Ajd6D8E8WrRB47q7d", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "g5CQgjbPH7NoytyMw", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "s9NgtsiR7WbjgeKLr", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "NPtZMHkAdqySShD3a", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "XxpWREjutAjbgHyME", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "6ZsiL2ZgidWjk3cgb", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "pvXiEaJgkuHEKijbB", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
{ "_id" : "im4GzumrE6RARNLbe", "created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z") }
```

I'm puzzle as to how this can happen. The result which I was expecting would be (timestamps):

```
"created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:51.183Z")
"created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:41.183Z")
"created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:31.183Z")
"created" : ISODate("2016-04-06T04:59:21.183Z")
```

I suspect it's something wrong with my function with the sort, hence my question how I can easier find the minimum of a date in MongoDB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your insert?

Comment: The insert comes at a later stage. This is part of an app with more than 10000 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found an error in my projection, the 4th line has to be:

```
res = Cards.findOne({ kit: kitUser }, { fields: { created: 1 }, sort: { created: 1 } });
```

I've overlooked that the projection is one object and therefore the first bracket has to be around all the options like `fields` and `sort`.

This article has been very helpful in identifying it and thanks to Marcel Fahle for pointing to it:

https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/mongodb-queries-and-projections/